# ¿como puedo editar una tabla en mysql con java?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, java-ee, update

les comento que estoy haciendo un código para hacer un crud con jsp y servlets ,el servicio de mostrar la tabla de la base de datos me funciona , el de agregar a la base de datos tambien me funciona, el problema esta cuando quiero editar que los campos me aparecen en null, la verdad llevo mas de dos semanas en esto y no se que es espero su ayuda.

estos son las clases que estoy utilizando:
la clase para la conexion

```
package Config;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
// esta clase hace posible la conexion con la base de datos sql
public class Conexion {
    Connection con;
    public Conexion(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital","root","");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }
    }
    public Connection getConnection(){
    return con;
    }
}
```

la clase interface para decir que metodos va a utlizar:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Interfaces;

import Modelo.Paciente;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author mateo
 */
public interface CRUD {
        public List listar();
    public Paciente list(int id);
  
    
    public boolean add(Paciente per);
    public boolean edit(Paciente per);
    public boolean eliminar(int id);
}
```

la clase que implementa los metodos de la clase CRUD:

```
package PersonaDAO;

import Config.Conexion;
import Interfaces.CRUD;
import Modelo.Paciente;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author mateo
 */
public class PacienteDAO implements CRUD {
  Conexion cn = new Conexion();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Paciente p = new Paciente();

    @Override
    public List listar() {
        ArrayList<Paciente>list=new ArrayList<>();
     String sql ="select * from pacientes";
        try {
            con = cn.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
            Paciente pac = new Paciente();
                     pac.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                     pac.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                     pac.setFecha(rs.getString("fecha"));
                     pac.setIdentificacion(rs.getString("identificacion"));
                     pac.setTidentificacion(rs.getString("tidentificacion"));
                     pac.setEps(rs.getString("eps"));
                     pac.setHistoria(rs.getString("historia"));
                     list.add(pac);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Paciente list(int id) {
        
     String sql ="select * from pacientes where id="+id;
        try {
            con = cn.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
          
                    p.setId(rs.getString("id"));
                    p.setNombre(rs.getString("Nombre"));
                    p.setFecha(rs.getString("fecha"));
                    p.setIdentificacion(rs.getString("identificacion"));
                    p.setTidentificacion(rs.getString("tidentificacion"));
                     p.setEps(rs.getString("eps"));
                     p.setHistoria(rs.getString("historia"));
                   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
     return p;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Paciente per) {
        String sql="insert into pacientes(nombre,fecha,identificacion,tidentificacion,eps,historia)values('" +per.getNombre()+"','"+per.getFecha()+"','"+per.getIdentificacion()+"','"+per.getTidentificacion()+"','"+per.getEps()+"','"+per.getHistoria()+"')";
        try {
            con=cn.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
     return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean edit(Paciente per) {
             String sql="update pacientes set nombre='" +per.getNombre()+"',fecha='"+per.getFecha()+"',identificacion='"+per.getIdentificacion()+"',tidentificacion'"+per.getTidentificacion()+"',eps='"+per.getEps()+"','historia="+per.getHistoria()+"'where id="+per.getId();                                                                
     
        try {
            con = cn.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean eliminar(int id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
  
}
```

la clase que me hace un objeto de tipo paciente:

```
package Modelo;

import PersonaDAO.PacienteDAO;


public class Paciente {
   int id;
   String nombre;
   String fecha;
   String identificacion;
   String tidentificacion;
   String eps;
   String historia;

    public Paciente() {
    }

    public Paciente(int id, String nombre, String fecha, String identificacion, String tidentificacion, String eps, String historia) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.identificacion = identificacion;
        this.tidentificacion = tidentificacion;
        this.eps = eps;
        this.historia = historia;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getIdentificacion() {
        return identificacion;
    }

    public void setIdentificacion(String identificacion) {
        this.identificacion = identificacion;
    }

    public String getTidentificacion() {
        return tidentificacion;
    }

    public void setTidentificacion(String tidentificacion) {
        this.tidentificacion = tidentificacion;
    }

    public String getEps() {
        return eps;
    }

    public void setEps(String eps) {
        this.eps = eps;
    }

    public String getHistoria() {
        return historia;
    }

    public void setHistoria(String historia) {
        this.historia = historia;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
   
}
```

la clase controlador que es un servlet

```
package Controlador;

import Modelo.Paciente;
import PersonaDAO.PacienteDAO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author mateo
 */
public class Controlador extends HttpServlet {
    String listar="vista/listar.jsp";
    String add = "vista/add.jsp";
    String edit= "vista/edit.jsp";
    Paciente p= new Paciente();
    PacienteDAO dao = new PacienteDAO();
    int id;
  
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Controlador</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Controlador at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
             String acceso="";
             String action = request.getParameter("accion");
             if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("listarp")){
             acceso=listar;
             }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
      acceso=add;
      }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Agregar")){
      
      String nom =request.getParameter("txtNombre");
      String fecha = request.getParameter("txtFecha");
      String identificacion = request.getParameter("txtIdentificacion");
      String tidentificacion = request.getParameter("txtTidentificacion");
      String eps = request.getParameter("txtEps");
      String historia = request.getParameter("txtHistoria");
      p.setNombre(nom);
      p.setFecha(fecha);
      p.setIdentificacion(identificacion);
      p.setTidentificacion(tidentificacion);
      p.setEps(eps);
      p.setHistoria(historia);
      
      
      dao.add(p);
      acceso=listar;
      }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")){
      request.setAttribute("idper", request.getParameter("id"));
      acceso=edit;
      }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Actualizar")){
      id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtid"));
      String nom=request.getParameter("txtNombre");
                
      String fecha=request.getParameter("txtFecha");
                 System.out.println(fecha);
      String identificacion=request.getParameter("txtIdentificacion");
      String tidentificacion=request.getParameter("txtTidentificacion");
      String eps=request.getParameter("txtEps");
      String historia =request.getParameter("txtHistoria");
      p.setId(id);
      p.setNombre(nom);
      p.setFecha(fecha);
      p.setIdentificacion(identificacion);
      p.setTidentificacion(tidentificacion);
      p.setEps(eps);
      p.setHistoria(historia);
      
      dao.edit(p);
      acceso=listar;
      }
         RequestDispatcher vista= request.getRequestDispatcher(acceso);
         vista.forward(request, response);
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

y luego esta el jsp:

el index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <a href="Controlador?accion=listarp"><input type="button" value="Pacientes"/></a>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

el listar que esta dentro de la carpeta vistas:

```
 <%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="Modelo.Paciente"%>
    <%@page import="PersonaDAO.PacienteDAO"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <h1>Pacientes</h1>
                <a href="Controlador?accion=add">Agregar</a>
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>NOMBRE</th>
                            <th>FECHA</th>
                            <th>IDENTIFICACION</th>
                            <th>TIDENTIFICACION</th>
                            <th>EPS</th>
                            <th>HISTORIA</th>
                            <th>ACCIONES</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <%
                      PacienteDAO dao = new PacienteDAO();
                      List<Paciente>list = dao.listar();
                      Iterator<Paciente>iter= list.iterator();
                      Paciente per = null;
                      while(iter.hasNext()){
                          per=iter.next();
                      
                    %>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= per.getId()%></td>
                            <td><%= per.getNombre()%></td>
                            <td><%= per.getFecha() %></td>
                            <td><%= per.getIdentificacion() %></td>
                            <td><%= per.getTidentificacion() %></td>
                            <td><%= per.getEps() %></td>
                            <td><%= per.getHistoria ()%></td>
                            
                            <td>
                                
                                <a href="Controlador?accion=editar&id=<%= per.getId()%>">Edit</a>
                                <a >Remove</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <% } %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

el añadir dentro de la carpeta vistas:
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <h1>Agrega paciente</h1>
        
        <form action="Controlador">
            Nombre:<br>
       
        <input type="text" name="txtNombre"/><br>
        Fecha de nacimiento<br>
        <input type="date" name="txtFecha"/><br>
        Identificacion<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtIdentificacion"/><br>
        Tipo de identificacion<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtTidentificacion"/><br>
        EPS<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtEps"/><br>
        Historia clinica<br>
        <textarea name="txtHistoria" rows="10" cols="85"/></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Agregar"><br>
        <a href="Controlador?accion=listarp">Regresar</a>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

y finalmente el metodo editar que cuando quiero editar me sale todos los campos en null:

```
<%@page import="PersonaDAO.PacienteDAO"%>
<%@page import="Modelo.Paciente"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
         <%
          PacienteDAO dao = new PacienteDAO();
          int id= Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("idper"));
          Paciente p = (Paciente)dao.list(id);
          
         %>
       <h1>Modifica Paciente</h1>
        
        <form action="Controlador">
            Nombre:<br>
       
            <input type="text" name="txtNombre" value="<%= p.getNombre()%>"/><br>
        Fecha de nacimiento<br>
        <input type="date" name="txtFecha " value="<%= p.getFecha()  %>"/><br>
        Identificacion<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtIdentificacion"value="<%= p.getIdentificacion()  %>"/><br>
        Tipo de identificacion<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtTidentificacion" value="<%= p.getTidentificacion()  %>"/><br>
        EPS<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtEps" value="<%= p.getEps()  %>"/><br>
        Historia clinica<br>
        <textarea name="txtHistoria" rows="10" cols="85"value="<%= p.getHistoria()  %>"/></textarea><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtid"value="<%= p.getId()  %>">
        <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Actualizar" ><br>
        <a href="Controlador?accion=listarp">Regresar</a>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

y esta es la base de datos de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `request.getAttribute("idper")` el nombre del parámetro en la url es `id` no `idper`

Comment: hola, en que clase encontraste ese error?

Comment: En la vista donde está la lista de pacientes, en esta línea: `<a href="Controlador?accion=editar&id=<%= per.getId()%>">Edit</a>` Ahí el parámetro se llama `id`

Comment: esa optiene el id no?

Comment: esta ? request.setAttribute("idper", request.getParameter("id"));

Comment: En el controlador hago  request.setAttribute("idper", request.getParameter("id")); con eso obtengo el id y luego en la vista edit lo llamo asi <%
          PacienteDAO dao = new PacienteDAO();
          int id= Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("idper"));
          Paciente p = (Paciente)dao.list(id);
          
         %>

Comment: Has depurado para ver si la variable `id` toma valor de `idper` en la vista de editar?

Comment: como lo podria hacer?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112521/discussion-between-lobos-and-francox17).

Answer (score 0):

mi programa tenia tres errores el primero era en el constructor ya que el id no tenia

```
 package Modelo;
    
    
    
    
    public class Paciente {
       int id;
       String nombre;
       String fecha;
       String identificacion;
       String tidentificacion;
       String eps;
       String historia;
    
        public Paciente() {
        }
    
        public Paciente(int id, String nombre, String fecha, String identificacion, String tidentificacion, String eps, String historia) {
            this.id = id;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.fecha = fecha;
            this.identificacion = identificacion;
            this.tidentificacion = tidentificacion;
            this.eps = eps;
            this.historia = historia;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
    
        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }
    
        public String getFecha() {
            return fecha;
        }
    
        public void setFecha(String fecha) {
            this.fecha = fecha;
        }
    
        public String getIdentificacion() {
            return identificacion;
        }
    
        public void setIdentificacion(String identificacion) {
            this.identificacion = identificacion;
        }
    
        public String getTidentificacion() {
            return tidentificacion;
        }
    
        public void setTidentificacion(String tidentificacion) {
            this.tidentificacion = tidentificacion;
        }
    
        public String getEps() {
            return eps;
        }
    
        public void setEps(String eps) {
            this.eps = eps;
        }
    
        public String getHistoria() {
            return historia;
        }
    
        public void setHistoria(String historia) {
            this.historia = historia;
        }
    
    }
```

el segundo en la consulta para actualizar los datos:

```
 String sql="update pacientes set nombre='" +per.getNombre()+"',fecha='"+per.getFecha()+"',identificacion='"+per.getIdentificacion()+"',tidentificacion='"+per.getTidentificacion()+"',eps='"+per.getEps()+"',historia='"+per.getHistoria()+"'where id="+ per.getId();
```

y el tercero en la vista edit el txtFecha tenia un espacio:

```
<%@page import="PersonaDAO.PacienteDAO"%>
<%@page import="Modelo.Paciente"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
         <%
          PacienteDAO dao = new PacienteDAO();
          int id= Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("idper"));
          Paciente p = (Paciente)dao.list(id);
        
         %>
       <h1>Modifica Paciente</h1>
       
        <form action="Controlador">
            Nombre:<br>
            
            <input type="text" name="txtNombre" value="<%= p.getNombre()%>"/><br>
        Fecha de nacimiento<br>
        <input type="date" name="txtFecha" value="<%= p.getFecha()  %>"/><br>
        Identificacion<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtIdentificacion"value="<%= p.getIdentificacion()  %>"/><br>
        Tipo de identificacion<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtTidentificacion" value="<%= p.getTidentificacion()  %>"/><br>
        EPS<br>
        <input type="text" name="txtEps" value="<%= p.getEps()  %>"/><br>
        Historia clinica<br>
        <textarea name="txtHistoria" rows="10" cols="85"/><%= p.getHistoria()  %></textarea><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtid"value="<%= p.getId()  %>">
        <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Actualizar" ><br>
        <a href="Controlador?accion=listarp">Regresar</a>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias a lobos por la ayuda